# How to search only approved posts using ps_search gem for Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, pg-search

I'm doing to multi search for Post and Website tables. I have is_approved boolean for all records. Currently, pg_search finds all posts, but I need to show only the posts which have is_approved==true.

I know I can check in the loop with "if" state to is_approved field but it doesn't sound very efficient. I believe pg_search would have a better way to limit.

Cheers,

---

_header.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag search_index_path, method: :get do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], placeholder: "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

---

search_controller.rb

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @pg_search_result = PgSearch.multisearch(params[:query])
  end

end
```

---

pg_search.rb

```
PgSearch.multisearch_options = {
  using: {
    tsearch:  { dictionary: 'english' }
  }
}
```

---

post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  include PgSearch
  multisearchable :against => :title
```

---

website.rb

```
class Website < ApplicationRecord

  include PgSearch
  multisearchable :against => [:title, :website_url]
```

Comment: As per doc (https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#chaining-method-calls-onto-the-results), this `PgSearch.multisearch(...).where(is_approved: true)` should work.

Comment: Yes when I try that I get StatementInvalid error:
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column pg_search_documents.is_approved does not exist
LINE 1: ..._search_ce9b9dd18c5c0023f2116f.pg_search_id WHERE "pg_search...

Answer (score 0):

Try using default_scope in required model. For example,

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch
  default_scope { where(is_approved: true)}
  multisearchable :against => :title
```